# DOM Operation Unsuccessful - Show HTML in Element

Tags: javascript, dom, visibility, textnode

Working code here is mixed with non-working code. The code works up until the line where it commands the innerText to be of

```
x.innerHTML.substring(3,-3)
```

This is the function I am calling on a click `EventListener` for "click". It does go to the function, I do get the console.log appearance. I do not get the change in text from empty to `String` and nor does it show up in the `coded_grove` portion of the code.

```
function makeOverSetup(ev)
{
        document.getElementById("styleVals").value = ev.target.getAttribute("style")
        document.getElementById("thisClasses").value = ev.target.getAttribute("class")
        document.getElementById("thisId").value = ev.target.getAttribute("id")
        document.getElementById("tagName").value = ev.target.tagName
        x = document.createElement("div");
        text = document.createTextNode(ev.target.outerHTML);
        x.appendChild(text);
        x.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
        console.log(x.innerHTML);
        if (document.getElementById("coded_grove").childElementCount.length == 0)
                document.getElementById("coded_grove").appendChild(x.firstChild);
        document.getElementById("coded_grove").firstChild.innerText = (x.innerHTML.substring(3,-3))
        elemCurrentNode = ev.target
        clicked = true
}
```

[This is the site.](http://g0d.me) Thank you in the future.

Comment: `if` condition never passes, `element.childElementCount` is a number, which doesn't have `length` property. `firstChild` could be a text node, it doesn't have `innerText` property.

Comment: @Teemu I'm making it into a textarea. Its got the best feel to it. I'm very happy now. I've just gotta make it appear now in the screen. I hoping it doesn't take much. Would I be to bold as to change the code?